# Parse json with big integer in R

Tags: r, regex, jsonlite

I have json

```
"{\"old_value\":\"Active\",\"new_value\":\"Inactive\",\"campaign_id\":23845817785350401,\"type\":\"run_status\"}"
```

with `campaign_id = 23845817785350401` as integer.
When I'm trying to parse it, I have some issue:

```
"{\"old_value\":\"Active\",\"new_value\":\"Inactive\",\"campaign_id\":23845817785350401,\"type\":\"run_status\"}" %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
$old_value
[1] "Active"

$new_value
[1] "Inactive"

$campaign_id
[1] 23845817785350400

$type
[1] "run_status"
```

Where campaign_id was parsed incorrectly. 
How to parse it like character or add quotation marks inside json for campaign_id?
Thanks!

Comment: For "big" integers R converts these to Double values (as R does not inherently have 64 bit integers). You could use any number of packages such as `mpfr` to handle 64 bit integers.

Comment: @Oliver: why not streat it as a string?

Comment: @Oliver, yes I can, but after `fromJSON` which one return already wrong number

Comment: If you get too frustrated with fighting with R big number parsing, just use `stringr::str_extract(json, '(?<="campaign_id":)\\d+')
`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I thought about this, but hope there is more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since parsing the long number ends in loss of data, you probably can rely on a regex extraction here.

You may use

```r
x <- "{\"old_value\":\"Active\",\"new_value\":\"Inactive\",\"campaign_id\":23845817785350401,\"type\":\"run_status\"}"
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(x, '(?<="campaign_id":)\\d+')
# => [1] "23845817785350401"
```

That is, it extracts one or more digits (with `\d+`) that occur right after a `"campaign_id":` substring.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/glTBNU) and [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wLQ4yr/1).

Comment: Is this still the most up-to-date answer? Still no json-library supporting bit64 or other "BigInt"-implementations out there?